# Pandas - extract numeric values from string column using replace + regex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column with many value ranges. Example below:

```
dirty_col = pd.Series([5, 6, '1-2', '40-60', 10])
```

I am trying to clean up this column producing a new column with the average of the value ranges. Expected result:

```
clean_col = pd.Series([5, 6, 1.5, 50, 10])
```

I am trying to map this using regex in vectorized mapping functions, something like:

```
clean_col = pd.Series([5, 6, '1-2', '40-60', 10]).replace({'^[0-9]-[0-9]$':--average here--},regex=True)
```

But I am stuck here. How could I get the expected result above USING a mapping dictionary and regular expressions? I am aware I could work directly in the dataframe spliting the text by '-' and then averaging out, but, I already have many other cleaning mappings inside above dictionary, that it would be more convenient and cleaner to keep using the same dictionary for all the cleaning.

I think the solution I am looking for probably uses lambdas, or an extra function that gets called from inside the dictionary, but I cannot figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `pandas.Series.replace` supports callable. One possible way using `pandas.eval`:

```
dirty_col.replace({'^(\d+)-(\d+)$': "(\\1+\\2)/2"},regex=True).apply(pd.eval)
```

Output:

```
0     5.0
1     6.0
2     1.5
3    50.0
4    10.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try `series.str.replace` with `repl` as a callable and `fillna` back

```
f_repr = lambda m: str(sum(map(int, m[0].split('-')))/2)
s_out = s.str.replace(r'^[0-9]+-[0-9]+$', f_repr).fillna(s)

Out[30]:
0       5
1       6
2     1.5
3    50.0
4      10
dtype: object
```

Comment: +1 for your input, but as I explain in the post above, I was looking for a dictionary-based solution. Regards.